# How to cartographically generalise buildings/settlements in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, generalization

I have a set of buildings in a polygon layer which I'm going to use in a 50k map. Since the buildings are tiny I cannot show the actual form of the building, instead I'm taking the centroid of the polygon and then make a point symbol (a square) which is a lot larger than the buildings original form.

When I do this in rural areas this is fine, but when there are a lot of tiny buildings near each other I have to do some kind of generalisation.

I have managed to remove smaller buildings that are in a certain distance from larger buildings (using buffer), but when I have a lot of buildings with the same size I'm not sure how to solve this.

Here are some images:
[image: original building polygons]
*This image shows the original size of the building polygons*

[image: centroid point building symbols]
*This image shows building symbols created from centroid of each building. As you can see this doesn't look good*

[image: the goal]
*This is somewhat what I'd like to achieve. I have removed some of the buildings manually.*

Any ideas?

I've seen that ArcGIS has a function called *Simplify Building* which is similar to whad I'd like to achieve. Unfortunately Open Source applications on OSX is the only possibility right now.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth checking out GeOxygene. I believe that has various generalisation algorithms so there may be something for building aggregation or building displacement within that:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/oxygene-project/
It is OpenSource but not for QGIS. I did used to have the OpenJump plugin for it installed, but not any longer so I can't check it out for you unfortunately.

Another option might be to try and improve the aesthetics of the results of your centroid method. Perhaps by using a line simplification algorithm on the polygon geometry. It won't look like your intended display but might communicate clusters of buildings sufficiently well for a 50k map. You could try using GRASS using v.generalize to do this and there maybe QGIS plugins too.

The aim would be to create a polygon areas representing clumps of buildings or the whole urban zone, rather than buildings. Bearing in mind this is 50k this might be OK.

Comment: I'll look into GeOxygene. Could you explain more what you mean about the other option? Simplify the geometries in order to get a little displaced centroids?

Comment: What I meant is use the output from your current method (the black polygons of image 2) within a line/polygon simplify routine. I thought maybe the main reason this is not aesthetically pleasing is the jagged boundaries.

Comment: I updated my other answer

Comment: The black objects aren't polygons. They are point objects which have the symbol of a black square!

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean now. Yes That's an option too actually. But most of the times these clusters are too small for using a settlement polygon I think. I think it would make people think it's more settlement than it is (just a few houses).